# Prometheus: Scrape logs from horizontal scaled microservices

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, prometheus, horizontal-scaling, prometheus-pushgateway

I want to use prometheus to scrape metrics from my distributed web service.
I have four kind of services setup with docker-compose or kubernetes.

Flask: 5000
Redis-Queue: 6379
Prometheus
Workers: Horizontally scaled based on system load. They get their working instructions over the redis Queue.

It is strait forward how to scrape metrics from Flask.
However, what is best-practise to get the metrics from the Workers? I cannot bind a port to them, because, I do not know, how many of them exist.

I was thinking about using a prometheus pushgateway. However, as I found out, this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer depends whether your workers lifetime is long or short

if a worker lives to execute a single task and then quits push gateway is the correct way to send metrics from the worker to Prometheus.

if a worker lives for at least two Prometheus scrape periods (which is configurable) you can definitely open a port on the worker and have Prometheus scrape metrics from a dedicated endpoint.

Prometheus's default scrape configuration comes with a [scrape job](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus/values.yaml#L1709) that will scrape any pod with the following annotation:

```yaml
prometheus.io/scrape: true
```

it also derives the scrape endpoint from the following annotations on the pod

```yaml
prometheus.io/scheme: http
prometheus.io/path: /metrics
prometheus.io/port: 3000
```

so you can easily annotate worker pods with the above annotations to direct Prometheus to scrape metrics from them

Comment: can you clarify how can we make that the worker lives more than two Prometheus scraping periods?

Comment: the worker is 100% in your control so it depends on the way you implement it - if you have a worker that constantly consumes messages and executes upon them it will probably leave long enough. If your worker processes a single message and goes down it might not live long enough.